# How can I aggregate microservices' swaggers into a single swagger

Tags: swagger, api-gateway

I am trying to generate a single swagger in my microservices project, aggregating all services' swaggers into a single one, in the API Gateway. In order to achieve this, I am following [this tutorial](https://objectpartners.com/2017/09/28/aggregate-services-into-a-single-swagger).

The problem here is that, when I try to set absolute URLs, the output I am receiving is `Failed to load API definition. undefined http://localhost:8070/apihttp://localhost:8081/api/v2/api-docs` where `localhost:8070/api` is the base URL for the api gateway, and `localhost:8081/api/v2/api-docs` is the docs URL of the swagger of the microservice.

Here is my code:

**SwaggerConfiguration**

```java
package com.rfd.apigateway.swagger;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "swagger")
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

  private List<Resource> resources;

  public List<Resource> getResources() {
    return resources;
  }

  public void setResources(List<Resource> resources) {
    this.resources = resources;
  }
}
```

**Resource**

```java
package com.rfd.apigateway.swagger;

public class Resource {
  private String name;
  private String url;
  private String version;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getUrl() {
    return url;
  }

  public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public String getVersion() {
    return version;
  }

  public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
  }
}
```

**DocumentationController**

```java
package com.rfd.apigateway.swagger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResourcesProvider;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@Primary
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DocumentationController implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {

  private SwaggerConfiguration swaggerConfiguration;

  @Autowired
  public DocumentationController(SwaggerConfiguration swaggerConfiguration){
    this.swaggerConfiguration = swaggerConfiguration;
  }

  @Override
  public List get() {
    List resources = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Resource resource : this.swaggerConfiguration.getResources()){
      resources.add(createSwaggerResource(resource));
    }

    return resources;
  }

  private SwaggerResource createSwaggerResource(Resource resource) {
    SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
    swaggerResource.setName(resource.getName());
    swaggerResource.setUrl(resource.getUrl());
    swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion(resource.getVersion());
    return swaggerResource;
  }
}
```

Finally, the **application.yml**

```yaml
swagger:
  resources:
    - name: transactions
      url: http://localhost:8081/api/v2/api-docs
      version: 1.0
    - name: payments
      url: http://localhost:8083/api/v2/api-docs
      version: 1.0
```

And a couple of images that can help to understand the problem:

Api Gateway Swagger URL
[image: Api gateway swagger URL]

Microservice api-docs URL
[image: Microservice api-docs URL]

Comment: you have to give url for the docs. what is this `/api` ?

Comment: The URLs that I'm setting in yml file are the microservices swagger URLs. I have a controller that redirects calls to /swagger-ui.html when asking for base URL (in this case, /api is the prefix for all calls), so basically when you access to localhost:808x/api, you are accessing to the swagger of the microservice.

Comment: okay. lets step back a bit.  The service which is running here  http://localhost:8070/api. How do you access swagger ui of this service?

Comment: I have edited my question thanks to your comment, I wasn't pointing to the api-docs path, but the problem still persists. localhost:8070/api is the api gateway with "api" prefix, and I have a controller that redirects from /api to /api/swagger-ui.html, so accessing to localhost:8070/api, I receive the swagger screen with the error message.

Comment: Precisely, I was about to say that you are not pointing your url's to api-docs. Good that you figured it out. what error message are you gettting

Comment: I have updated the question with a couple of images that can help to understand the problem. Thanks pvpkiran

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164682/discussion-between-darthroman-and-pvpkiran).

Comment: Actually, it was fixed in 2.9.0 release github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2372

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was just the springfox version... I tried to downgrade it from 2.8.0 to 2.7.0 and it worked like a charm. It seems it is a recognized bug, as you can see here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2235

I also had to enable cors in microservices but that is another problem.

Comment: Actually, it was fixed in 2.9.0 release https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2372

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by using: https://github.com/varghgeorge/microservices-single-swagger

This simple sprintboot microservice can display all your swagger documentation in one place. Based on YAML configuration, it will display the list of services and provide a single documentation server for all services. In the YAML config, you can add different swagger URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This issue reappeared in version 3.0.0. And it hasn't been fixed. Everyone is waiting for version 3.0.1. A temporary solution is to download springfox-swagger-ui.jar. There, replace springfox.js. And generate jar again. And then exclude this jar from the main dependency and slip it manually.

```
implementation("io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0") {
    exclude(group = "io.springfox", module = "springfox-swagger-ui")
}
implementation(files("libs/springfox-swagger-ui-3.0.0.jar"))
```

Here is a link to a discussion of this issue:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3413
you will also find a new springfox.js file there